# Let $f: \mathbb{R}-\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\left| \cos(\frac{1}{x}) \right|$ Why is f not differentiable in $\frac{2}{\pi}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $f: \mathbb{R}-\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\left|\cos(\frac{1}{x}) \right|$ Why is f not differentiable in $\frac{2}{\pi}$?

If we take the difference quotient: $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{\left| \cos(\frac{\pi}{2+ \pi h}) \right| - \left|cos(\frac{\pi}{2})\right|}{h}$$

Why does the limit not exist at $\pi /2$?

Comment: it should be $\cos \bigg(\frac{1}{\frac{2}{\pi}+h} \bigg)$

Comment: What makes you say that $f$ is not differentiable at $\frac{2}{\pi}$?

Comment: The question asks whether f is differentiable and the solution says that it isn't, because it supposedly is not differentiable in $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: What you wrote is not the difference quotient. Where do the absolute values come from?

Comment: Sorry f was meant to be $f(x) = \left| cos \frac{1}{x} \right|$. I'll correct the title.

Comment: In that case, look first at the simpler function $g(x) = \lvert \cos x\rvert$. Draw a sketch of the graph maybe. In what points is that function not differentiable (and why)? The claim about $f$ follows directly.

Comment: OK, there is still an error in the expression you wrote, since $f(x+h)$ is not $\left|\cos\bigl(\frac{\pi}2+h\bigr)\right|$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Looking at the graph, it seems to be that the limits of the difference quotient at the points $\frac{2z}{\pi}, z \in \mathbb{Z}$, are negative in the case of h approaching 0 from the left and positive for h approaching 0 from the right. Is that correct? How could I argue this by using the difference quotient, evaluating the difference quotient would lead an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ I think.

Comment: You got the points wrong (they're $$\frac{1}{\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi},\quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$$ actually), but the principle is indeed: we have a positive limit from the right, and a negative limit from the left, so the (two-sided) limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the absolute value sign that makes it nondifferentiable at ${2 \over \pi}$. The function
$\cos({1 \over x})$ is equal to zero at $x = {2 \over \pi}$, is positive to the left of $x = {2 \over \pi}$, and is negative to the right of $x = {2 \over \pi}$. 
Thus to the left of $x = {2 \over \pi}$, you have $|\cos({1 \over x})| = \cos({1 \over x})$, while to the right of $x = {2 \over \pi}$, you have $|\cos({1 \over x})| = -\cos({1 \over x})$.

So the left-hand derivative of $|\cos({1 \over x})|$ will be given by ${d \over dx} \cos({1 \over x})\big|_{x = {2 \over \pi}} = {1 \over x^2}\sin({1 \over x})\big|_{x = {2 \over \pi}} = {\pi^2 \over 4}$. On the other hand, the the right-hand derivative of $|\cos({1 \over x})|$ will be given by ${d \over dx} (-\cos({1 \over x}))\big|_{x = {2 \over \pi}} = -{1 \over x^2}\sin({1 \over x})\big|_{x = {2 \over \pi}} = -{\pi^2 \over 4}.$ Since these are not the same, the function is not differentiable at ${2 \over \pi}$.

Comment: In other words, the function has a *corner* at $x=2/\pi$. The graph near $2/\pi$ looks like a V. (Zarrax is right, I just wanted to add a detail that may help understanding.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $f(x+h) = \cos\left(\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+h}\right)$. So you should try to evaluate: $$\lim_{h \to o} \frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+h}\right) - \cos \left(\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos\left(\frac{2}{\pi + 2h}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)}{h}$$
However, this is not necessary because $1/x$ is differentiable in $\pi/2$ and $\cos x$ is differentiable in $2/\pi$. This way, $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}\sin(1/x)$, and $f'(\pi/2) = \frac{4}{\pi^2}\sin(2/\pi)$.